# Bootstrap navbar-fixed-top overlapping carousel slider

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, overlapping

So, want put a navbar-fixed-top in my nav. The proposal is that my nav follow when scrolling page. But the difficulty is that my nav is overlapping the section right below in this case, my carousel slide.

here de jsfiddle 
https://jsfiddle.net/fhvo7anz/

```
<header class="container-fluid">
    <div class="container bghead navbar-fixed-top ">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
          <a href="#"><img class="img-responsive" src="images/logo.png"></a><br>
          </div>
              <div class="col-md-8">
                  <nav class="navbar navbar-default bgnav">
                      <div class="container-fluid">
                        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                        <div class="navbar-header">
                          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
                            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                          </button>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li><a href="#">Home<span class="sr-only"></span></a></li>
                            <li class="dropdown">
                              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Institucional <span class="caret"></span></a>
                              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Institucional</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Missão, Visão e Valores</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Organograma</a></li>
                                <!--<li role="separator" class="divider"></li>-->
                              </ul>
                            </li>
                              <li><a href="#">Atividades</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                              <li><a href="#">Contato</a></li>
                          </ul>
                            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
                            <div class="form-group">
                              <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Procurar">
                            </div>
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Ir</button>
                          </form>
                        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
                      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
                    </nav>
              </div>
        </div> 
    </div>
    </header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your CSS:

```
#carousel-example-generic {
    margin-top:150px;
}
```

Comment: tks for the help @pedrodj46 But the problem is the difference that we can see when responsive mobile.

Comment: But the problem is that the menu is over the carousel? In mobile version what is the problem? I see your jsfiddle perfectly with the `margin-top:150px`

Comment: It occurs with different mobile resolutions the margin-top having this fixed size does not monitor these variations. This menu is collapse, your height size can change.

Comment: Ok but your menu not collapsed in jsfiddle.

Comment: you might want to try giving everything below the menu a position and top property, similar to this: 

#everything_under_menu {
position: relative;
top: 150px; }